# Sending Html Text via ajax (html) to php script to store in db. It only saves until &nbsp;

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, encoding

i got the following js script submitting form html content:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'include/speakers.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : "htmlText="+htmlField",
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function (result) {
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $( ".phpMessage" ).html( " - "+thrownError );
        }
    });
```

Speakers Php Looks like:

```
$htmlTextVar = $_POST['htmlText'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET htmlText = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $htmlTextVar, $id);  
$stmt->execute();
```

Now, the issue is when I submit html text like

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span>
```

its only storing the text until `&nbsp;`. So text inside the database table is

`<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">`

Have no idea how to solve this :(

Comment: show `htmlField` declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your data on `encodeURIComponent()`

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'include/speakers.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : "htmlText=" + encodeURIComponent(htmlField),
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function (result) {
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        $( ".phpMessage" ).html( " - "+thrownError );
    }
});
```

and on your php file

```
$htmlTextVar = urldecode($_POST['htmlText']);
```

Comment: @jQuery if it solves your question, you can click it as the accepted answer :)